# If android application is installed in mobile but never launched .is BootCompletedReciever called?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted, android-reboot

If android application is installed in mobile but never launched and considered i have implemented boot completed receiver for this application.Now i am going to reboot the device .here boot completed receiver will call or what will happens?

Answer (score 0):

No You have to launch the app once to register receiver with the device. Without launching the application Device will not detect your broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

> Set the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in your application's manifest. This allows your app to receive the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED that is broadcast after the system finishes booting (this only works if the app has already been launched by the user at least once)

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot) clearly states that it works only if the app has been launched at least once. So the answer of your question is NO, it wont be called.